# CrossOrigin annotation and setHeader make the same thing?

Tags: java, spring, cors

I am a little bit confused.

```
@GetMapping
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8107")
public String getSomeText(){
   return "Hello world";
}

@GetMapping
public String getSomeText(HttpServletResponse response){
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:8107");
    return "Hello world";
}
```

Does this two methods do the same job?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, setting header manually is naive way of saying allow the request from this origin and this approach is limited to just doing that.Also, it is limited to the API where you set this header.

On the other hand, `@CrossOrigin` provides you flexibility of configuring it on the controller level as well as request mapping level.

Also, `@CrossOrigin` will set other default values like `DEFAULT_ALLOWED_HEADERS`, `DEFAULT_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS`, `DEFAULT_MAX_AGE`.

Setting the header manually might not work always, since there will be many filters which can override the value set by you in the controller.

So I would say neither of these two are recommended. Configure a CORS config bean and give your configurations over there. An example is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```